# My images are not appearing in react when im trying to import them

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make an image slider, but the pictures are not appearing; not sure why. Here's the code below if anyone can help

```
import service1 from '../assets/service1.jpg'
import service2 from '../assets/service2.jpg'
import service3 from '../assets/service3.jpg'


const slides = [
    {url: {service1}},

    {url: {service2}},

    {url: {service3}},
];
```

Here's where I'm setting up my image slider to go left and right.

```
const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0)

    const prevSlide= () => {
        const isFirstSlide = currentIndex === 0
        const newIndex = isFirstSlide ? slides.length - 1: currentIndex
        setCurrentIndex(newIndex)
    }

    const nextSlide = () => {
        const isLastSlide = currentIndex === slides.length - 1
        const newIndex = isLastSlide ? 0 : currentIndex + 1
        setCurrentIndex(newIndex)
    }

    const goToSlide = (slideIndex) => {
        setCurrentIndex(slideIndex)
    }

<div className= 'max-w-[1400px] h-[580px] w-full m-auto py-4 px-4 relative group'>
          <div className='w-full h-full rounded-2xl bg-center bg-cover duration-500' style={{backgroundImage: slides[currentIndex].url}}>
          </div>
```

right here is where I'm mapping out everything. I don't think I'm doing anything wrong here; I think it's how I'm importing the pictures.

```
<div className='flex top-4 space-x-2 justify-center py-2'>
                {slides.map((slide, slideIndex) => (
                    <div className='text-xl cursor-pointer' key={slideIndex}>
                      <BiCircle onClick={(() => goToSlide(slideIndex))} size={10}/>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
```

Comment: where is `currentIndex`. Did u map this div correctly?

Comment: i edited my question so you can see where

Comment: Shouldn't this be `{url: service1},` instead of `{url: {service1}},` ?

Comment: ...and the syntax for setting the background image doesn't look right either. You can see [this tutorial](https://reactgo.com/react-background-image/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

React backgroundImage should follow this:

```
styles={{ backgroundImage:`url(${picture})` }}
```

So, In your code should change to:

```
<div className= 'max-w-[1400px] h-[580px] w-full m-auto py-4 px-4 relative group'>
          <div className='w-full h-full rounded-2xl bg-center bg-cover duration-500' style={{backgroundImage:`url(${slides[currentIndex].url})` }}>
</div>
```

You can try it, Hope it can help!